# a href with onclick not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, safari

Why does the this link not working on Safari?
when i click on the `Click here` it should open the `http://othersite.com` and also the `http://mysite.com/profile`. The problem is that it only opens `http://mysite.com/profile` and it doesn't open a new tab for `http://othersite.com`. This one works on Chrome and firefox..how can i make it working on Safari?

**html**

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="redirect()" href="http://othersite.com">Click here</a>
```

**javascript**

```
function redirect(){
    location.href = 'http://mysite.com/profile';
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

And in order to open your link in a new tab you have to set the target attribute to `_tab` , `_blank` opens a new tab or a new window depending on user's settings.

Comment: this doesn't even come close to answering the question.  Additionally it does not work.